# updating access database record with form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I need some help creating an Access database to record hours worked / amount charged by employee.  Simplified, each employee charges hours to specified work codes.  I pull a report that lists all codes and the amount of dollars available to charge to.  This report is uploaded into Access 2007 as `Work_Codes_Table`.  The data in the report cannot be modified.

I need to create a form that shows the available work codes and allows the employee to enter the amount they will charge to each separate code.  This data will be saved into `Employee_Hours_Table`, leaving the original data unchanged.  I want to save this data for future reference.

Right now I have the `Work_Codes_Table` setup correct and a split form that shows all of the active work codes, but I am stuck on the next piece.

Comment: This site is geared towards people who have a specific issue they need to resolve.  It's just guys like you and me, helping each other out.  This sounds more like you want someone to do your job, which is way beyond the scope of SO.  Keep plugging away and if you come across a **specific** roadblock, feel free to come back and ask.

Comment: So what's your question? Please, clarify.

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  I am not looking for someone to do my job, I have done all the work myself and will continue to do all the work myself.  That's why my inquiry was so generic.  I was also generic because I am learning this on the fly.  From my searches this site seemed like my best bet to talk with people that knew what they were talking about.

My roadblock right now is an input field on my form for employees to input the amount charged to specific codes.  I have the form and added the field, but when I put in an amount it assigns that amount  to all records instead of the one.